# Roots of polynomials with coefficients in an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I have encountered to a famous problem about polynomials. Could you please show me the outline of achieving to it.

**Question**: Let $\kappa$ be an algebraically closed field. How could we show that every polynomial $F(x,y) \in \kappa[x,y]$ has infinite number of roots?

Comment: First you need to exclude constant polynomials. Then note that an algebraically closed field has infinitely many elements.

Comment: Hint: Choose $a \in \kappa$ be arbitrary, and consider the polynomial $F(x, a)$ in one variable $x$.

Comment: "Famous problem about polynomials" - which one? Surely not that $V(F)$ is infinite?

Comment: @Johannes: Not every $a$ works (but almost all).